# Ctypes array access variables changed by C

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have a function in C which is integrated into python as a library.
The python looks something like this:

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np
lib=ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./array.so")
lib.eq.argtypes=(ctypes.c_int,
                 ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float),  
                 ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))
params = parameters.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))
results = np.zeros(5).ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))
lib.get_results(ctypes.c_int(5),params,results)
```

And the C code in array.c looks something like:

```
void get_results(int size, float params[], float results[5])
{
   'do some calculations which use params'
   results[0] = ...
   results[1] = ...
   results[2] = ...
   results[3] = ...
   results[4] = ...
}
```

How would one access the array(pointer) `results` in python? I couldn't figure it out since the void function in C doesn't actually return any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  The input arrays need to be `dtypes=np.float32` (or `ct.c_float`) to match the C 32-bit `float` parameters.  `results` is changed in-place so print the updated `results` after the function call.

You can also use `ndpointer` to declare the *exact* type of arrays expected, so `ctypes` can check the the correct array type is passed.  In your original code `np.zeros(5)` defaults to `np.float64` type.

**test.c**

```c
#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

API void get_results(int size, float params[], float results[5])
{
    // Make some kind of calculation
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        results[0] += params[i];
        results[1] += params[i] * 2;
        results[2] += params[i] * 3;
        results[3] += params[i] * 4;
        results[4] += params[i] * 5;
    }
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct
import numpy as np

lib = ct.CDLL('./test')
# Since you are using numpy, we can use ndpointer to declare
# the exact type of numpy array expected.  In this case,
# params is a one-dimensional array of any size, and
# results is a one-dimensional array of exactly 5 elements.
# Both need to be of np.float32 type to match C float.
lib.get_results.argtypes = (ct.c_int,
                            np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float32, ndim=1),
                            np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float32, shape=(5,)))
lib.get_results.restype = None


params = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.float32)
results = np.zeros(5, dtype=np.float32)
lib.get_results(len(params), params, results)
print(results)
```

Output:

```
[ 6. 12. 18. 24. 30.]
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```py
import ctypes
import numpy as np
from os.path import abspath
from ctypes import cdll, c_void_p, c_int

params = np.ascontiguousarray(np.zeros(5, dtype=np.float64))
results = np.ascontiguousarray(np.zeros(5, dtype=np.float64))

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(abspath('array.so'))      # loading the compiled binary shared C library, which should be located in the same directory as this Python script; absolute path is more important for Linux — not necessary for MacOS
f = lib.get_results       # assigning the C interface function to this Python variable "f"
f.arguments = [ c_int, c_void_p, c_void_p ]         # declaring the data types for C function arguments
f.restype = c_int      # declaring the data types for C function return value
res = f(params.size, c_void_p(params.ctypes.data), c_void_p(results.ctypes.data))   # calling the C interface function
print(res)
print(results)
```

```c
int get_results(int size, double * params, double * results)
{
   /* do some calculations which use params */
   results[0] = ...;
   results[1] = ...;
   results[2] = ...;
   results[3] = ...;
   results[4] = ...;
   return whatever;
}
```